# Tap and hold: a pain in the uiBUTTon

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Excuse the bad pun, I'm creating a custom tab bar in my iPhone app using UIButtons. Everything works beautifully except that when I tap and hold a button, it doesn't select it until I release it. It's really bugging me, because a standard UITabBarItem is selected on touch down and it just feels wrong.

I've set the IBAction to "Touch Down" and my code is pretty simple. Am I doing something wrong?

```
-(IBAction)tab1Pressed:(id)sender 
{
    if (self.tab1.selected == NO) {
        self.tab1.selected = YES;
        self.tab2.selected = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is actually quite a nice capitalization pun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got a solution! Added a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to each UIButton, instead of using IBActions. Worked like a charm!

In viewDidLoad:

```
tapAndHold = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapAndHold)];
[tapAndHold setMinimumPressDuration:0.01];
[self.myTabBarButton addGestureRecognizer:tapAndHold];
[tapAndHold release];
```

Comment: Whoops, don't think there's any reason to make that an instance variable. First line should be: UILongPressGestureRecognizer *tapAndHold etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should use another event for your button. The default one is "touch up inside". The action is triggered when you release the button.

Using "touch down" should do what you want.

Comment: ...although the question does say, "I've set the IBAction to 'Touch Down'", so that may not be the problem here...

Comment: So strange. Why would "touch down" not be working? It just behaves exactly like "touch up inside". I would try subclassing but I would have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can try subclassing a UIView and implementing touchesBegan:withEvent: method.

Comment: Wait, do you mean I could try subclassing UIButton and implementing touchesBegan:withEvent: with my tab changing method?

Comment: No, a UIView. you can also do custom drawing in its drawRect method.